# Why were the pines roaring?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, music, poetry

The following line appears in the [second song of the dwarves](http://genius.com/J-r-r-tolkien-far-over-the-misty-mountains-cold-full-version-annotated) in The Hobbit:

> The pines were roaring on the heights

I've never been near a forest fire or a pine forest that wasn't on fire, so I'm not familiar with the sounds of either.

Is this line already talking about the fire? I could imagine a big forest fire "roaring".
But google tells me that there's a large amount of references to "roaring pines" without mention of fire. Is "roaring" just something pines do?

Comment: The wood makes a peculiar cracking, "whoosh" kind of sound when it burns which is more pronounced if fire's intensity is high. I believe the roar is a metaphor for that

Comment: If you want to learn why it makes such a sound, [see here](http://wonderopolis.org/wonder/why-does-wood-crackle-when-it-burns/)

Comment: You've "*never been near a ... pine forest that wasn't on fire*"??

Comment: It's "The pines were roaring on the heights". Is this question even remotely on-topic? Let's move this to English.se or perhaps Botany.se. A dictionary would tell you that the word "roar" or the verb "roaring" can be used to describe a fire: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/roaring Further it can be used to describe a constant booming noise, so even wind through trees could be described as a roar, like the ocean can roar. However, this verse is *about* burning trees. The poem also describes the trees blazing with light like torches ...also not a normal function of non-burning pine trees

Comment: I am familiar with the phrase "a roaring fire"...The reason I asked is because up to this point, the fire wasnt mentioned and the next line "the wind was moaning in the night" doesn't refer to the fire either. Since Tolkien is fond of using old language and I did find references to roaring pines on google, I was wondering if there was any way this could refer to a sound that pines just make in the wind.

Comment: @GorchestopherH - Questions about the use of language in a work as heavily on-topic as LOTR are very suitable for SFF:SE.

Comment: @erzet Anything can roar. Is that your question? Or are you asking what the poem is describing? Check the dictionary link, the word roar can be used to describe almost any noise. Wind in the trees can be described as a roaring (as per the dictionary).

Comment: @Valorum The question appears to be asking if roaring can be used to describe pines that are not on fire, which it certainly can, which has nothing to do with the poem. If the question is asking if the poem is talking about burning pine trees or non-burning pine trees the answer is all too obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the following lines, it's pretty clear that the author was describing a forest fire;

> **The fire was red, it flaming spread,
>
>   The trees like torches blazed with light.**

Pine trees are filled with [pine oils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pine_oil) which emit a **bright, vivid flame** and a **specific noise** when burned. The heat was also sucking in air (hence the wind moaning).

An entire *row* of them aflame would be appallingly loud, hence "roaring".

Comment: For reference, the only real-world references to "roaring pines" is a place named after a wildfire station, [a book about wildfires](http://www.pelicanpub.com/proddetail.php?prod=9781589805224#.V0grXvkrLcc) and a couple of shops and a band named after the place

Comment: Any fire can roar, not just pine fires. However, in the poem the verse is specifically describing a burning pine forest.

Comment: @Valorum Huh, I don't know how I missed the fact that all those pages I found were actually about the same thing. It looks like that one store is very prolific online.

Comment: @erzet - If you watch their corporate videos, it looks like they have three social media staff for every one warehouseman.

Comment: Real world: anything can roar, even without fire. They are not exclusive. Wind can roar through the trees (pines). Oceans can roar without being on fire. Lions can roar without being on fire. So can an old truck.

Comment: @GorchestopherH - That's very true. But in this context they were roaring because they were on fire.

Comment: @Valorum Obviously. But if the OP was only asking if the poem is talking about fire or not, this is the most blatantly obvious question that is still open.

Comment: Not only that, but the dragon's wings as he passed would have generated a lot of wind, which fed the fire, and when the wind rushes through the trees like that, I can imagine a roaring sound being made.

Answer (score 2):

The specific line you've referenced is the first line of three verses that describe the arrival of Smaug at the Lonely Mountain:

> The pines were roaring on the heights,
>   The wind was moaning in the night,
>   The fire was red, it flaming spread,
>   The trees like torches blazed with light.
>
> The bells were ringing in the dale,
>   And men looked up with faces pale.
>   The dragon's ire, more fierce than fire,
>   Laid low their towers and houses frail.
>
> The mountain smoked beneath the moon.
>   The dwarves, they heard the tramp of doom.
>   They fled the hall to dying fall
>   Beneath his feet, beneath the moon.

Pines only roar when on fire. The forest is on fire because of the dragon. The roaring pines are the poem's first reference to this fire.

A large forest fire also creates a wind, due to the oxygen being pulled in to feed the fire, and the hot air from the fire rising into the atmosphere. This is the moaning wind.

Just in case the reader/listener missed the references to fire there, the next two lines make things pretty clear by explicitly mentioning fire and flames, as well as saying that the trees blazed like torches.